# Application initialization

Tags: android, bluetooth, classcastexception

I am currently making an application which only has three classes. Two Activities, and an Application class. From what I have learned of Applications so far, the class initializes itself at the start of the program, so does that mean I do not need to initialize an Object of the class in each Activity?

My program crashes at the start every time and is returning a ClassCastException, which I'm assuming has to do with my Application class since it is the only class casting I am doing in all of my code. As a local variable I have

```
protected BluetoothApplication myBt;
```

and inside my onCreate() method I call

```
myBt = (BluetoothApplication)getApplication();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to initialise it manually but you can use `getApplicationContext()` to get the instance of your Application Class for eg:-

```
MyApplication application = ((MyApplication)getApplicationContext());
```

You can also access Application class from a Non-Activity class by passing a Context to that class and then using that context for getting the instance of Application class by,

```
MyApplication application = ((MyApplication)context.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: So getApplicationContext() should be used as opposed to getApplication()?

Comment: Yes, you have to use `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 1):

Is the BluetoothApplication a custom subclass of Android's default Application-class? If so, then do you tell Android in your AndroidManifest.xml to use that class instead of the default Application class?

See [Android Application API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) for more details.